# Opencv how to use MatIterator to iterate on color image with float RGB value?

Tags: c++, image, loops, opencv, mat

I am studying using opencv to iterate on Mat, as the tutorial said, we can use `MatIterator_` to iterate Mat. For 3 channel uchar image, we can use `MatIterator_<Vec3b>` as below:

```
MatIterator_<Vec3b> it, end;
for( it = I.begin<Vec3b>(), end = I.end<Vec3b>(); it != end; ++it)
{
      //do any iteration stuff
}
```

But I am not sure whether it would work on 3-channel float value (32FC3) Mat?

And what is the exact definition of `Vec3b`?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will work just well by using `Vec3f` instead:

```
MatIterator_<Vec3f> it, end;
for( it = I.begin<Vec3f>(), end = I.end<Vec3f>(); it != end; ++it)
{
      //do any iteration stuff
}
```

The reason is that `Vec3f` and `Vec3b` share the [similar structure](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#Vec):

```
typedef Vec<uchar, 3> Vec3b;
typedef Vec<float, 3> Vec3f;
```